# Where does the Encryption of ViewState (ViewStateEncryptionMode) happen?

Tags: asp.net

It could be a basic question on this topic. I am reading that the View State can be encrypted, by setting the ViewStateEncryptionMode.

Even when the ViewStateEncryptionMode is not specified, the __VIEWSTATE hidden filed seem to be having encrypted values.

Assuming this is based on the default value ViewStateEncryptionMode.Auto, I set the page's ViewStateEncryptionMode to Never. Still I see the same value (in encrypted form) in the hidden field.

Is ViewStateEncryptionMode is dealing with something else than, the __viewstate hidden field? Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even when the ViewStateEncryptionMode is not specified, the
>   __VIEWSTATE hidden filed seem to be having encrypted values.

No, the ViewState is BASE64-Encoded, not encrypted.

For instance, go to this page: http://lachlankeown.blogspot.com/2008/05/online-viewstate-viewer-decoder.html and copy and paste your ViewState's value to decode it.

For this page: http://www.telerik.com/support/demos/developer-tools-demos.aspx

returns this: [image: decoded view state]

Comment: That's a nice information. Now I understand. Thank you @luarus.